# Child blocks not called when calling a template file from another template file

Tags: blocks, template

I am using social login plugin that overrides the default customer login form template in this way :

```
<customer_account_login>
       <reference name="customer_form_login">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>ced/sociallogin/customer/form/login.phtml</template></action>
            <block type="persistent/form_remember" name="persistent.remember.me" template="persistent/remember_me.phtml" />
            <block type="core/template" name="persistent.remember.me.tooltip" template="persistent/remember_me_tooltip.phtml" />
            <block type="sociallogin/login" name="ced_sociallogin_login">
                <block type="sociallogin/google_button" name="ced_google_login_button" />
                <block type="sociallogin/facebook_button" name="ced_facebook_login_button" />
                <block type="sociallogin/twitter_button" name="ced_twitter_login_button" />
                <block type="sociallogin/linkedin_button" name="ced_linkedin_login_button" />
                <block type="sociallogin/yahoo_button" name="ced_yahoo_login_button" />
            </block>
        </reference>
    </customer_account_login>
```

Now I am calling this block in another template file like this:

```
 <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/form_login')->setTemplate('ced/sociallogin/customer/form/login.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

This template - "login.phtml" has a small list of child methods called in this way:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('persistent.remember.me'); ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('persistent.remember.me.tooltip'); ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml("ced_sociallogin_login"); ?>
```

But none of them are being called.. Why is this so??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I am calling this block in another template file like this:

No, you don't. You create a *new instance* of the block, which knows nothing about the hierarchy in which the existing blocks is located.

The block with its children is created by the XML definition, *on the customer login page*. If you are on this page, you can retrieve, modify and output the block like this:

```
 <?php echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('customer_form_login')->setTemplate('ced/sociallogin/customer/form/login.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

If you are on a different page, you need to copy the XML to the layout handle for this page first.